# Type Inference in tuples?

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

```
let http404Error = (statusCode: 404, statusMessage: "Not found")
print(http404Error.0, http404Error.1)
```

I got some questions and "problems" with tuples:

**Question 1:**
But what if I want the statusCode to be an Int and an Int only?
Because "statusCode: Int = 404" doesn´t seem to work?

**Question 2:**
What if I want to shorten the part "print(http404Error.0, http404Error.1)?
Is there a short way to write it, something like print(http404Error.[0, 1])?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What about using `typealias`?

Comment: As to the second question, if in debug mode, you can use Mirror(reflecting: http404Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let http404Error:(Int,String) = (statusCode: 404, statusMessage: "Not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you also have a solution to question 2?

Comment: you can do `print(http404Error)`

Comment: Sure, but what if I got for example 8 different values and I want to call 2-5, is there a quick way to do it, or each time http404Error.2, http404Error.3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For specifying the type, you can define a type alias like:

```
typealias HttpStatus = (statusCode: Int, statusMessage: String)
let http404Error     = HttpStatus(403, "Not found")
print(http404Error.0, http404Error.1)
```

For shortening the print statement, I don't think there is an easy way to do that. One thing you can do is, you can create a custom function which takes the tuple as argument, formats the values and returns a string.

```
func getStatus(_ status: HttpStatus) -> String {
    return "\(status.statusCode) \(status.statusMessage)"
}

print(getStatus(http404Error))
```